# inputs in datatable with pagination loses modified values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The datatable with editable fields and pagination does not update the modified values in the controller when paging.

The controller has the ViewScoped scope of Omnifaces.

When I change the page of the table, the values entered are not saved in the model and when doing sumbit only the values ??of the current page are sent.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mROqF.png)

Code of xhtml

```
<h:form>
   <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
   <p:dataTable var="obj" id="tabla"
                rows="6" paginator="true"
                value="#{pruebaController.lista}">
       <p:ajax event="page" process="tabla" update="tabla"/>
       <p:column>
           <h:outputText value="#{obj.texto}"/>
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
           <p:inputText value="#{obj.valor}"/>
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   <p:commandButton value="Guardar" update="@all" process="@all" action="#{pruebaController.guardar}"/>
</h:form>
```

Code of controller

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named("pruebaController")
@ViewScoped
public class PruebaController implements Serializable {

    private List<Prueba> lista;

    public List<Prueba> getLista() {
        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<Prueba> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Prueba("uno", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("dos", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("tres", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("cuatro", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("cinco", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("seis", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("siete", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("ocho", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("nueve", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("diez", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("once", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("doce", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("trece", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("catorce", ""));
        lista.add(new Prueba("quince", ""));
    }

    public void guardar() {
        for (Prueba p : lista) {
            System.out.println(p.getTexto() + " ----- " + p.getValor());
        }
    }
}
```

Code of model

```
package es.prueba;

public class Prueba {

    private String texto;
    private String valor;

    public Prueba(String texto, String valor) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Versions

- Primefaces: 6.0.21 or 6.1.4
- Mojarra: 2.2.14
- Omnifaces: 2.6.4
- Weld: 2.4.4.Final

Comment: So it works if you remove the `process="tabla"`? And an 'editable datatable' https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml is something different than inputs in a datable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on each page change the component goes to the backing bean and refreshes with the values in there. I had the exactly same problem and solved easily only by adding a `<p:ajax event="change" />` after the field I wanted to keep the data. This forces the field to update the value in java backend, avoiding the lost of data at page changes.

My case:

```
<p:column headerText="#{message['label.modeloSplitter.cor']}" rendered="#{modeloSplitterMB.entity.modelo == 'C'}">
            <h:selectOneMenu id="corFibras" value="#{item.cor}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{corMB.corSelectItems}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
```

How I think it will solve in your case:

```
<p:column>
    <p:inputText value="#{obj.valor}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" />
</p:column>
```